# How to use a module properties file in a Android project

Tags: android, gradle

I've got an Android module where we use a `.properties` file.

I use the content of the properties file in the `build.gradle` for one of the `manifestPlaceholders` and in the Kotlin codebase too via BuildConfig.

So in my `build.gradle` I load the file with:

```
rootProject.file("src/main/java/com/MyCompany/myModuleName/myProperties.properties").withInputStream { myProperties.load(it) }
```

Then I load the properties in the BuildConfig and use them with manifestPlaceholders:

```
android.defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", 'MY_URL', "\"${myProperties.getProperty('MY_URL')}\""

        manifestPlaceholders = [
                "foo": myProperties.getProperty('fooProperty')
        ]
}
```

When I compile the module, it works fine, I can see the content of the `BuildConfig` and use the properties in my codebase with:

```
BuildConfig.MY_URL
```

The problem is when I use the module in my Android project, gradle complains because it can't find the property file
`/Users/myUser/pathToProject/android/src/main/java/com/myCompany/myModuleName/myProperties.properties (No such file or directory)`

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use properties file from module but here it is you can do it

```
def myFile = new File("$projectDir/src/main/java/com/MyCompany/myModuleName/myProperties.properties")
def myProperties = new Properties()
myProperties.load(new FileInputStream(myFile))
```

You need to use projectDir instead of rootProject